When will you ((have | be able) to) give the money back? Will that be a problem for you?
It seems to me that the first 2 of the three answers can be correct in this exercise:
When _____ give the money back? Will that be a problem for you?

will you have to
will you
will you able to

And "will you be able to" would also be possible.
Am I right?
Source: https://naurok.com.ua/test/read-the-pairs-of-sentences-choose-the-word-a-c-which-fits-both-sentences-66724.html

3 is ungrammatical, and even if corrected in an obvious way (I shall not say how) would be illogical. Think about the second sentence of the question ('Will that be a problem for you?'). Only one answer is both grammatical and likely.

@MichaelHarvey Why would "When will you be able to..." be illogical?

It says: 3. will you able to. I have no way of knowing whether there was a 'be' in the original test question, and you omitted it in your question above, or whether it was absent in the test itself. From what I have seen quite often on here, it seems that tests can be very badly constructed.,

As for the illogicality, think about the probability of a 'problem'. 1. When someone has to give the money back, 2. when they give the money back, or 3. when they are able to give the money back. Which of these situations probably isn't going to be a problem?

@MichaelHarvey "that" may refer not to "being able to give the money back" but to "giving the money back"

It's common for tests to carelessly overlook a valid option and present only one as the answer. If this is just for your own learning and there's no penalty or need, then simply ignore this test. Reading through the early questions, I see multiple valid answers for almost all of them.

@AndyBonner You mean, you opened the link and read all the questions in the test created by that foolish teacher?

We often say "When will be able to pay me back".

@Wittyhaire Just the first 5 or so. Since "be" is missing in "will you able to" in that original, and was not your mistake, it might be the test making the mistake on purpose to make that choice a wrong one. But for instance, in question 2, both "mustn't" and "shouldn't" seem equally fine to me.

@Wittyhaire Interestingly: At first I turned on Google Auto-translate to English to try to see instructions (I didn't find any); the "be" in "will you be able to" is so required that Google added it!

@AndyBonner Yes, question 2 lead me to exactly the same thoughts. And when I first read "will you able to" my brain automatically added be (the headline to this post still contains it) there. When Michael Harvey pointed it out, I realized that 'be" was missing.

You're correct that answer 3 is not possible, because the grammar is simply incorrect. You correctly determined that "be" needs to be inserted before "able".
Logically, answer 2 doesn't make much sense. The time that you plan on giving the money back is usually when it's not a problem, so asking if it will be a problem would be redundant. You normally only ask that when you're talking about a proposed action.
That leaves only answer 1. This asks about the time when you're required to return the money, which may not actually be convenient for you. So the second question is reasonable. If you say it's a problem, the other person might be able to assist.
